# Change position of l shaped arrows in tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

I am trying to change the location of the l-shaped arrows in the following chart. Basically I want the arrows coming off of "Regimes of sovereign states" to start lower in the box (lower on the y axis) so that they don't interfere with the "Non-regimes" box. Is there a simple way to do this?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{arrow}=[draw, -latex]
\tikzstyle{tblock} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{autoblock} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!20]

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Concept Ladder of Regime Types: Residual vs. Substantive Authoritarianism\\}
\vspace*{10mm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (state) [tblock, text width=3cm] {States of the world};
\node (reg) [tblock, below left= 1cm and .25cm of state, text width=3cm] {Regimes \\ (of sovereign states)};
\node (nonreg) [autoblock, below right= 1cm and .25cm of state, text width=3cm] {Non-regimes \\ (anarchy, foreign \\ occupation, transition)};
\draw [arrow] (state) -- (reg);
\draw [arrow] (state) -- (nonreg);
\node (demone) [tblock, below left=2cm and .25cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Democratic regimes};
\draw [arrow] (reg) -| (demone);
\node (auto) [autoblock, below right=2cm and 4.5cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Authoritarian regimes \\ (substantive authoritarianism)};
\draw [arrow] (reg) -| (auto);
\node (lfs) [autoblock, below = 2cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Limited franchise \\ systems};
\draw [arrow] (reg) -- (lfs);
\node (dfr) [autoblock, below right=2cm and .25cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Dominant faction \\ regimes};
\draw [arrow] (reg) -| (dfr);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}`
```

I haven't actually tried anything to fix this because I don't really know where to start. I googled "change length of l shaped arrows tikz" and came up with nothing. If you have any suggestions, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

- `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, use `\tikzset` instead
- your example is missing the float package

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={draw, -latex}}
\tikzset{tblock/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white}}
\tikzset{autoblock/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!20}}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Concept Ladder of Regime Types: Residual vs. Substantive Authoritarianism\\}
\vspace*{10mm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (state) [tblock, text width=3cm] {States of the world};
\node (reg) [tblock, below left= 1cm and .25cm of state, text width=3cm] {Regimes \\ (of sovereign states)};
\node (nonreg) [autoblock, below right= 1cm and .25cm of state, text width=3cm] {Non-regimes \\ (anarchy, foreign \\ occupation, transition)};
\draw [arrow] (state) -- (reg);
\draw [arrow] (state) -- (nonreg);
\node (demone) [tblock, below left=2cm and .25cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Democratic regimes};
\draw [arrow] (reg.south) -- ++(0,-1cm) -| (demone);
\node (auto) [autoblock, below right=2cm and 4.5cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Authoritarian regimes \\ (substantive authoritarianism)};
\draw [arrow] (reg.south) -- ++(0,-1cm) -| (auto);
\node (lfs) [autoblock, below = 2cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Limited franchise \\ systems};
\draw [arrow] (reg) -- (lfs);
\node (dfr) [autoblock, below right=2cm and .25cm of reg, text width=3cm] {Dominant faction \\ regimes};
\draw [arrow] (reg.south) -- ++(0,-1cm) -| (dfr);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]